# Getting current page URL when default permalink is set

Tags: permalinks

I am trying to get the current page url using this code.

`global $wp;
 $current_url = home_url( add_query_arg( array(), $wp->request ) );`

It works fine. But when default permalink settings (Plain) are in effect, it doesn't work.

How do I get this to work?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not use `get_the_permalink()`?

Comment: As far I understand that should be used inside the loop. I want something that I can use outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the current permalink outside *The Loop*, then do the following:

- Access the global `$post` variable
- `get_the_permalink($post->ID)`

Youf code as follows:

```
global $post;

echo get_the_permalink($post->ID);
```

Comment: The `$post` global is often polluted by other code, `get_queried_object()` would be safer in this case.

Comment: Hi Milo,

Can you please elaborate a bit on that?